# Angular Service not a global singleton

Tags: angular, typescript, angular7

I was under the impression that a `Angular Service` is a `Singleton`, but have recently discovered, or atleast it seems, that the service is only a singleton to the instance of the component and the component's children.

Consider the following code:

```
const CACHE_REFRESH_INTERVAL = 1800000; //30 minutes
const CACHE_SIZE = 1;

const COMPANY_CACHE_KEY = 'company_cache_key';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: "root"
})
export class CompanyService {

  private companyCache: Map<string, Observable<any>> = new Map();

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getAllCompanies(): Observable<CompanyViewModel[]> {
    if (!this.companyCache[COMPANY_CACHE_KEY]) {
      const timer$ = timer(0, CACHE_REFRESH_INTERVAL);
      this.companyCache[COMPANY_CACHE_KEY] = timer$.pipe(
        switchMap(_ => this.getAllCompaniesHttpRequest()),
        shareReplay(CACHE_SIZE),
        refCount(),
        catchError(err => this.companyCache[COMPANY_CACHE_KEY] = undefined) //prevents storing error in cache
      );
    }
    return this.companyCache[COMPANY_CACHE_KEY];
  }

  private getAllCompaniesHttpRequest(): Observable<CompanyViewModel[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<CompanyViewModel[]>(environment.endpoints.company.getAllCompanies());
  }
}
```

Let's say, `ComponentA` gets this service injected through the component's instructor.  When `ComponentA` calls the `CompanyService.getAllCompanies()` method, the results will be stored in `companyCache`.  Now the user navigates to a new URL, `ComponentA` get destroyed, as well as the instance of the service.  Navigate back to `ComponentA`, and a new instance of the service is injected, and `companyCache` is once again empty.

Is my assumption correct?  Can I make a service a singleton accross the entire application?

Comment: You're assumption is correct. I use a simpler version of this pattern in two apps. How are you qualifying `as well as the instance of the service`? Can you set up a stackblitz that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Just to add though, interesting caching pattern. I've largely moved away from handling client side caching in my app to using e-tags, so don't have to worry about this too much any more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services are a singleton at the level of the app.

Take this simple stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-k72vze)

I have a trivial service that sets a random number from the constructor.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service {
  constructor() {
    this.rnd = Math.random();
  }

  private rnd: number;

  getRand(): number {
    return this.rnd;
  }
}
```

I have a component structure like this with the service being injected into 2 "child" components (not actual children, but that's the pattern of navigation I have set up):

```
|- home

|- component a
|--  inject service

|- component b
|--  inject service
```

When navigating from home to component a, it will display the random number that was set in the constructor of the service.

When I navigate back to home (check the console to see that component a was destroyed), and then navigate to component b, it will display the random number that was set in the constructor of the service.

For the lifetime of the app, the random number remains the same. To me this proves that even when a service isn't "in scope", it is still in memory.

Not to mention that [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services) talk about this on the very first line:

> A singleton service is a service for which only one instance exists in an app.

Comment: @BradAxe mbojko is demonstrating how the singleton service can be overridden using the providers array on a component. I have forked my example to demonstrate this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-skdfwm. Component A continues to use the singleton, whereas Component B is using a local instance by declaring the service in the local providers. So Component A will always use the same instance, and Component B will use a new instance on each visit.

Answer (score 2):

> I was under the impression that a Angular Service is a Singleton, but have recently discovered, or atleast it seems, that the service is only a singleton to the instance of the component and the component's children.

That shall happen when you put your `CompanyService` inside the component's `providers` array. Services are singletons by default, but you can override that.

Take a trivial service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class SomeService {
  public someRandomValue = Math.random();

  constructor() {
    console.log("I've just got instantiated.");
  }
}
```

and two components that have `SomeService` in their providers array. For both of them, `someRandomValue` will be different, and "I've just got instantiated." will be logged twice:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-oua1nf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsome.service.ts

Comment: But you can see from the code above, that the CompanyService is set to: providedIn: "root"

Comment: Nevertheless, it can be overrided. Do you have it in a `providers` array somewhere?

Comment: This seems the logical explanation to me.

Comment: I had been working on this for hours! Thank you from 2024!